# Figuring out what package adds a "io" cookie in Laravel 8 without laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm bringing some changes to my Laravel 8 site in order to bring support for GDPR law. I figured out that a cookie named `io` is set when I go to my site pages.

According to some Google searches, it could be the package `laravel-echo-server`. But I didn't installed it. (https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/359)

I don't know how to rapidly discord the package that adds this cookie to my site. Does anyone already have this problem? What is the guilty package?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that at least one of these both packages adds this cookie named `io` (in npm's `package.JSON`):

```
  "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
  "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
```

I think they can be kept in development. And that they can be uninstalled when deploying the site in production.

Edit: they are under `devDependencies`